# How convert text to column in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview

I'm just starting to learn C#, and I have this problem...
How convert text to column in DataGridView from Excel source??

Source format:

```
NO  BRAND   NAME,ADRESS,PHONE
```

1   Brand1  Name1,adress1,phone1

2   Brand2  Name2,adress1,phone2

3   Brand1  Name3,adress3,phone3

4   Brand3  Name4,adress4,phone4

5   Brand1  Name5,adress5,phone5

6   Brand1  Name6,adress6,phone6

7   Brand4  Name7, adress7, phone7

8   Brand2  Name8,adress8,phone8

9   Brand4  Name9,adress9,phone9

10  Brand2  Name10,adress10,phone10

Excel sources:
https://www.easypaste.org/file/dmqoMGDW/export-sources.xls?lang=en

I want the table after importing to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG8Xe.png)

Thx all for help me...

This is my code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExceltoDGV
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.textBox1.Text = openfile1.FileName;

                    string pathconn = "Provider = Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR= yes;\";";
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathconn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Inwestycje$]", conn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach to convert my csv to a dataset. Try this:

```
private DataTable GetDataFromSource(string connectionstring)
    {
         DataTable DtCsv = new DataTable();  
         string Fulltext;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(connectionstring))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Fulltext = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString(); //read full file text  
                    string[] rows = Fulltext.Split('\n'); //split full file text into rows  
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        string[] rowValues = rows[i].Split(','); //split each row with comma to get individual values  
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < rowValues.Count(); j++)
                                {
                                    DtCsv.Columns.Add(rowValues[j]); //add headers  
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DataRow dr = DtCsv.NewRow();
                                for (int k = 0; k < rowValues.Count(); k++)
                                {
                                    dr[k] = rowValues[k].ToString();
                                }
                                DtCsv.Rows.Add(dr); //add other rows  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        return DtCsv;
    }
```